# How does the security of Elliptic curve compare to normal discrete logarithm?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, security-definition

**Intro:**

EC are often compared with RSA but how about a more safe version of the discrete logarithm?

All 3 can be reduced to the problem:

$$b = g^a \mod{P}$$

In RSA $P$ is a product of two primes. To solve the discrete logarithm 'just' a factorization of $P$ is required. Different to the two other cases $a,b$ is known and $g$ is searched.

But if $P$ is a prime the problem can get much harder. It depends at the factorization of $P-1$ because $P-1$ is also equal to the number of different elements.

As far as I know the best choice is a 'safe prime' with $P = 2 q +1$ with $q$ a prime as well.
This discrete logarithm can be solved in $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{q}) $ with $q$ the biggest prime factor (with Pollard's algorithm).

At EC $P$ is a prime as well but the number of elements can be different (but still $\approx P$). It can e.g. be determined with [Schoof's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%27s_algorithm).
A number of safe elliptic curves can be found at [safecurves.cr.yp.to](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to) .
Tested safe curves had all $2^3 \cdot q$ elemnts (with $q$ a big prime). Afak solving those will also take $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{q}) $ time.

---

**Question:**

Given the discrete logarithm solving problem for normal numbers and elliptic curves (mod a prime $P_i, P_e$). Given a valid generator $g_i, g_e$ and a possible result $b_i, b_e$.

$$\text{normal: } b_i = g_i^{a_i} \mod P_i $$
$$\text{elliptic curve: } b_e = g_e^{a_e} \mod P_e $$

Let the elliptic curve have $N_e = 2^3 \cdot q$ different elements with $q$ a big prime (other variables chosen in that way).

Let $$P_i = 2 \cdot q +1$$

Do both problems have the same solving time of  $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{q}) $ ?

(we ignore the linear factor of computation time for each single step due to different multiplication time)

---

**Bonus questions:**

Which other factor have impact into the solving speed?

BQ1.) The number of elements of some curves from safecurves.cr.yp.to had also the property: $N_e -1 = 3 \cdot r$ with $r$ a big prime. Does this have any impact?

BQ2.) Has the factorization of $P_e -1$ any impact at the security?

BQ3.) Has the factorization of $q-1$ any impact at the security? (for normal and EC)

---

**Edit: Update**

- It looks like 'number filed sieve' can do better than Pollard's algorithm ($\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{q}) $). To use it on EC the embedding need to be small -> chose a big one
- besides the safe prime property $P_i$ should als be not close to $p^n$ with $p$ a small prime like $2,3,..$

$\rightarrow$ assumption: so there is a difference?

Comment: https://www.keylength.com/en/compare/

Comment: @kelalaka ty4link. But unsure about the naming: I guess symmetric would be AES, But whats the difference between 'Factoring Modulus', 'Discrete Logarithm Key', 'Discrete Logarithm Group'.

Comment: Symmetric is a general name for symmetric ciphers like AES, ChaCha. Factoring Modulus RSA like, the two other is [realated to DSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88278/18298)

Comment: Interesting link but as far as I understood DSA is not exactly the same as the described normal discrete log problem. However it also operation at a sub-group generator with an order of 'Discrete Logarithm Key'-bit. This also supports the assumption of same computation time. During checking this links out I also noticed there is a faster method 'number filed sieve' and besides the safe prime property it should als not be close to $p^n$ with $p$ a small prime like $2,3,..$ Will add this

Comment: On the above comment: if one can solve the DLP in $\mathbb Z_p^*$, one can (trivially) solve DSA; for the converse, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71029/5555).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know the best choice is a 'safe prime' with $P=2q+1$ with $q$ a prime as well.

This is the best choice for a given size of $P$, but not for a given size of $q$. See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88654/555).

> This discrete logarithm can be solved in $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{q})$ with q the biggest prime factor (with Pollard's (Rho) algorithm).

Essentially yes (minor caveat: $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{q})$ is not effort, but the number of multiplications of integers of size $P$, with $P>q$, hence the effort grows faster by a factor at least $\ln P\,\ln\ln P$). That the DLP *can* be solved with such method and effort does not imply that such method or effort is *needed*. And if $P$ is a safe prime, there are methods (including the Number Field Sieve) requiring less effort. Again, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88654/555).

> Do (DLP in a subgroup of an appropriate Elliptic Curve on one hand, of $\mathbb Z_P^*$ on the other hand) have the same solving time of $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{q})$ (group operations, where prime $q$ is the order of the subgroup)?

Yes, when using Pollard's Rho algorithm. That algorithm is believed optimum in the Elliptic Curve case, and for $P$ large enough in the $\mathbb Z_P^*$ case.

No, when $P$ is a safe prime (and large enough to make the DLP non-trivial), and using the Number Field Sieve to tackle the DLP in the subgroup of $\mathbb Z_P^*$.

---

Note: I don't know that the Number Field Sieve can be used to solve the DLP in an appropriate Elliptic Curve (sub)group; and it would come as a huge surprise if it was more efficient than Pollard's Rho algorithm.

Comment: as far as I understood EC can be embedded in a $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ DLP. If the embedding degree $k$ is small NFS can be used at this. Depending at $k$ it can be faster. see [question1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37302/elliptic-curve-and-embedding-degree) and [question2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50387/can-curve25519-be-used-for-pairing-based-cryptography/50409#50409)

Comment: ty for answering this as well. This was the first question and the linked was a 2nd trial but it generally also answering this question. I didn't knew how to proceed with this question. I think I know the difference now (except maybe the relation for some special primes which are somewhere in between those cases but not needed now). Thank you again.